# Anchor Instruction Discriminators

Tags: anchor, rust

So let's imagine I have a program `my_program` with an instruction `do_something`. Given an ix:

```
let ix: solana_program::instruction::Instruction = ...
```

with `ix.program_id` equal to `my_program::id()`, how can I check if this instruction is `do_something` or not?

Answer (score 2):

As part of macros expansion Anchor generates the following code for your program's instructions:

```
pub mod instruction {
    /// Instruction.
    pub struct DoSomething {
        pub args: DoSomethingArgs,
    }

    // ...

    impl anchor_lang::Discriminator for DoSomething {
        const DISCRIMINATOR: [u8; 8] = [122, 77, 80, 159, 84, 88, 90, 197];
    }

    // ...
```

So by checking the first 8 bytes of `ix.data` and comparing them to the Anchor discriminator of `do_something` you can tell if this instruction is meant to be processed by `do_something` or not.

```
// NOTE: This line is required.
use anchor_lang::Discriminator;

// ...

let is_do_something_ix = ix.data[..8] == crate::instruction::DoSomething::DISCRIMINATOR
```

Answer (score 1):

Anchor uses the sha256 of "namespace":"function_name" as a function identifier. When you are creating your instruction:

```
    let instruction = Instruction {
        program_id, // whatever the program key is
        accounts: vec![
            AccountMeta::new(ctx.accounts.whatever.key(), false),
        ],
        data: get_function_hash("global", "do_something").to_vec(),
    };
```

```
pub fn get_function_hash(namespace: &str, name: &str) -> [u8; 8] {
    let preimage = format!("{}:{}", namespace, name);
    let mut sighash = [0u8; 8];
    sighash.copy_from_slice(
        &anchor_lang::solana_program::hash::hash(preimage.as_bytes()).to_bytes()
            [..8],
    );
    sighash
}
```

If the instruction also has args, you would need to serialize them and append them to the buffer for the function hash, e.g.

```
#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
struct CpiArgs {
    bump: u8,
}

fn get_ix_data(bump: u8, amount: Amount) -> Vec<u8> {
    let hash = get_function_hash("global", "do_something");
    let mut buf: Vec<u8> = vec![];
    buf.extend_from_slice(&hash);
    let args = CpiArgs { bump };
    args.serialize(&mut buf).unwrap();
    buf
}
```